# Nightmare JS click based on :contains

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, nightmare

Using NightmareJS, I would like to find the element based on keywords then click on that element. Here is what I have so far:

```
.evaluate(function() {
  $(':contains("Jacket")')
  //Now I need to find this and click on this how would I go about this?
})
```

This does not work

```
  .click(':contains("Jacket")')
```

Comment: Perhaps jQuery's [`trigger()`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) would be helpful, e.g. `trigger('click')`

Comment: I can click it using .click() from nightmare but what do I tell it to click?

Comment: `$(':contains("Jacket")').click();` ?

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette Not working, says its not a selector

Comment: And with a relevant tagname in front? Like `$('a:contains("Jacket")').click();` Or a class, like: `$('.link:contains("Jacket")').click();`